# Configure prometheus-operator to scrape static icmp targets from blackbox-operator

Tags: prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

How do I need to configure a `monitoring.coreos.com/v1` `Probe` to instrument my prometheus-operator to collect `icmp` metrics from a defined list of targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that you have installed both prometheus- and blackbox-exporter as follows:

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -n monitoring --create-namespace
helm install prometheus-blackbox-exporter prometheus-community/prometheus-blackbox-exporter -n monitoring
```

First you need to enable the `icmp` module of the blackbox-exporter in a values file, e.g. `blackbox-exporter.yml`:

```yaml
config:
  modules:
    icmp:
      prober: icmp
      icmp:
        preferred_ip_protocol: ip4

allowIcmp: true
```

apply the config:

```
helm upgrade prometheus-blackbox-exporter prometheus-community/prometheus-blackbox-exporter -f blackbox-exporter.yml
```

then you can define the `Probe` like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Probe
metadata:
  name: blackbox-probe-icmp
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    release: prometheus
spec:
  jobName: icmp
  interval: 1m
  scrapeTimeout: 5s
  module: icmp
  prober:
    url: prometheus-blackbox-exporter:9115
  targets:
    staticConfig:
      static:
        - 192.168.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
```